# Pine script array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have coded a script that takes, price level and then does some calculationson start price in loop and plots horizontal lines.

Currently i have number of lines to 9 with option to increase. I am facing issue when i increase number of lines.

I assume that arrays can hold 100,000 values. (i.e 100,000 values coming from calculations) however when i increase to even 13 it says array too large.

```
startprice = input.price(0, title = 'Start Price', confirm = true)
pricecycles= input.int(9, title = 'Price Cycles',maxval = 13)
oppsi = input.bool(true,title = "Change Direction",inline = 'direction')
startime = input.time(timestamp("Feb 01 2020 22:10:05"),title = 'start time', confirm = true)

endtme= input.time(timestamp("Feb 01 2020 22:10:05"),title = 'end time', confirm = true)



var float[] priceLevels = array.new_float(0)
for i = 0 to pricecycles
    opps = oppsi?(1.618 * 1* i) : (1.618* 1* i) * -1
    array.push(priceLevels, (startprice + opps))

for i = 0 to pricecycles
    line.new(startime,array.get(priceLevels, i),endtme,array.get(priceLevels, i), xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.none,color=color.yellow ,width = 1,style = line.style_dotted)
```

Part of code is given above.

Comment: ok i have checked with 1 set to loop its strange array.size says 28102 on gold. where as by code it should have 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

ok its fixed.

i just changed this line

```
var float[] priceLevels = array.new_float(0)
```

to

```
priceLevels = array.new_float(0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).